# Call requires API level 24 (current min is 8): new android.location.GnssStatus.Callback

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

[registerGnssStatusCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#registerGnssStatusCallback(android.location.GnssStatus.Callback)) was introduced in API 24. now `GpsStatus` is deprecated, but we can't use the new one for APIs prior to 24.

Now what? How can we use the new one in our old projects?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest sticking with the old call for awhile. This was only deprecated in API 24, which hasn't even officially been released yet. Even once it is released it'll likely only be used by a very small percent of devices in the immediate future (i.e. most people will still be old versions of Android for a long time). Besides, it's a big jump to go all the way from a min version of 8 to a min version of 24.

With that said, it is possible to do version-specific reasoning. See documentation below:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

This is probably obvious but the caveat here is you don't want to do code like the following:

```
if (version == x) {
  ...
}
else if (version == y) {
    ....
}
else if (version == z) {
   ...
}
```

I just point that out because I've actually seen people do stuff like that. (It's better to use some kind of Strategy/Template pattern along with a Factory in cases like that if possible).

Comment: what do you mean it's not released? I already have it in my sdk, when I change my project's build target to api 24 it shows this error, and if I use the old GpsStatus it warns me about deprecation. 
there should be some support library version of it for backward compatibility.

Comment: There are previews available but that's all they are - previews. Android 7's not officially released to the general public yet. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history . Also, the old version *is* still supported in libraries; they're not actually removing it at this point, it's just deprecated.